# How to check if an emission is null or not

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2, option-type

in the belwo code, i want to check if the "retrofit" object that was used as input to the map operator is null or not.
which operatopr i should use and how.

i would like to use Maybe observable to check the returned retrofit object is null or not before the .map operator is called.

**Activity**

```
companion object {
    fun create(): Observable<WikiApiService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                .build()
        )

            .map { retrofit -> retrofit.create(WikiApiService::class.java) }
            .toObservable()
    }
}
```

Comment: RxJava 2 enforces non null emissions, so would throw a null pointer if it was.  A better approach would be to create the object, then check what to do next i.e `retrofit?.let { Maybe.just(it).map { ... } } ?: Maybe.empty()` - assuming that the retrofit object could be null in the first place?

Comment: you mean i should add the code you provided inside the body of the map operator?

Comment: I have given pseudo code explaining my suggestion in line to your example, not "copy/paste". You should do known defensive checking upfront, that's what I'm suggesting, with the Elvis operator at any point if something is null you can return your fallback, default value.